# Issue in connecting via ODBC in C++ to Azure SQL database

Tags: c++, azure, odbc, azure-sql-database

This is my first question on StackOverflow, so please excuse my innocence!

Here's the issue: I'm trying to connect via ODBC on Windows in C++ to an Azure SQL database, but without success as I keep getting the following message:

```
[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0)
```

I retrieved the connection string from Azure and made sure my IP address is registered in the firewall settings.

Following the example provided by Microsoft, I'm connecting thru:

```
    _retcode = SQLDriverConnect(
        _hDbc,
        NULL,
        ( SQLCHAR * ) connectionString,
        SQL_NTS,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL,
        SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT );
```

where connectionString is defined as:

```
const char * connectionString = "Driver = { ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server };"
    "Server = tcp:<datasource>.database.windows.net, 1433;"
    "Database = <database>;"
    "Uid = <account>; Pwd = <password>;"
    "Encrypt = yes; TrustServerCertificate = no; Connection Timeout = 30;";
```

Also, I tried to connect via .NET in C# and it works with the following connection string build:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = "<datasource>.database.windows.net";
    builder.UserID = "<account>";
    builder.Password = "<password>";
    builder.InitialCatalog = "<datavase>";
```

I was able to perform the "SELECT @@VERSION" statement with the following result:

```
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8
    Feb 26 2020 10:26:43
    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
```

So what am I doing wrong???

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Try this -- get rid of the spaces between the attribute and the value.  For example, you have `"Database = <database>;"` instead of `"Database=<database>;"`.  The [syntax structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldriverconnect-function?view=sql-server-ver15) of the command does not suggest to have spaces between the attribute and value.

Comment: Thank you, Paul, for your suggestion. However, it is not working. Here's the new string:
const char * connectionString = "Driver={ ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server };Server=tcp:<datasource>.database.windows.net, 1433;Database=<database>;Uid=<account>;Pwd=<password>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;";

Comment: Also parameter 4 should be the length of the string you provided.  It's been a while since I've done ODBC programming extensively, but you have to read the docs for the function themselves, rather than looking at off-site samples (even from MS).  The documentation I linked to has an example, and the fourth parameter is the number of characters.

Comment: I'm using the SQL_NTS code for Null Terminated String. Let me try this.

Comment: Still the same result: [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0)

Comment: Is your application 32-bit or 64-bit?  The ODBC driver has to fit the bit-ness of your application.

Comment: I tried both Win32 and x64 in Debug mode without success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!
First, I provided the OutConnectionString information to display the working connection string, if any.

```
       SQLDriverConnect(hDbc,
                     GetDesktopWindow(),
                     pwszConnStr,
                     (SQLSMALLINT)wcslen(pwszConnStr),
                     OutConnectionString,
                     BufferLength,
                     &StringLength2Ptr,
                     SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE));
```

Then, I reverted to create a DSN file using the wizard that is launched when no command arguments are provided (in the Microsoft sample).

I managed to provide the right arguments and was able to connect to my Azure SQL database.

I printed the OutConnectionString and here's the result (quite far from what I was expecting):

```
const char * connectionString = "DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=<server>.database.windows.net;UID=<account>;PWD=<password>;Trusted_Connection=No;DATABASE=<database>;";
```

I then inserted the string above directly into my code, this time without a prompt:

```
    _retcode = SQLDriverConnect(
    _hDbc,
    NULL,
    ( SQLCHAR * ) connectionString,
    strlen( connectionString ),
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT );
```

And it's working!

For reference, here are the links to the official Microsoft documentation:

[Connect to SQL Database using C and C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-develop-cplusplus-simple)

[SQLDriverConnect Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldriverconnect-function?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Connect to an ODBC Data Source (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-an-odbc-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Windows with C++ : Using Databases on Windows Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/april/windows-with-c-using-databases-on-windows-azure)

Comment: Can you please post the links you used to try to get things working originally so that I can have the engineering and docs team review these pages to make sure that they are complete, correct, and more obvious? Thanks, Conor

Comment: Hello Conor, I Just did ;)

Comment: I asked the engineering team to go review the docs.  Thank you for posting this based on your experiences!  Conor